# What is the difference between OPB606 and TCRT5000?

Tags: sensor

I had to make a path following bot. I needed an [OPB606](http://optekinc.com/datasheets/opb606-607.pdf) sensor for that, however I couldn't manage. Instead I used [TCRT5000](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83760/tcrt5000.pdf), but the bot is not working. Is there a similarity between these two sensors? What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

The TCRT5000 has a slightly different pinout.
Its LED is oriented the opposite way to the one in the OPB606.
So you should have success if you simply reverse those 2 pins.